# Не получается словить ошибку MissingPermissions в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

я пытался словить ошибку разными способами, но никакой из них не подошёл.

```py
@buyrole.error
async def buyrole_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f'{config.error_emoji} Произошла ошибка', description = 'У меня нет права "Управлять ролями", либо моя роль ниже, чем покупная', color = discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

ошибка:

```
Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: ошибка связана с правами бота. Я в этом даже убедился

Comment: А что пишет `print(type(error))`?

Comment: <class 'discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError'>

Comment: Поискал про CommandInvokeError и вот он: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/9727b56503a8ae091b054ca228b17e405611f1fc/discord/ext/commands/errors.py#L501 Если я прав и `BotMissingPermissions` является исключением, то нужно так проверять: `isinstance(error.original, commands.BotMissingPermissions)`

Comment: не сработало
...

Comment: Ок, какой тип у `error.original`?